# VBA Script Not pulling data - Overlapping

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working the script below and I'm trying to pull data from another (target) workbook into the source workbook. The script is working, except it's only pulling a single row (it should be pulling 12+). After some debugging, I noticed that it's just overwriting the previous row, so I'm left with the last row from the target data. I'm not sure why it is doing this. I don't have any merged cells and there's nothing in the source workbook.

Here's the code:

```
Select Code
    Dim salesWB As Workbook
    Dim mrpWB As Workbook
    Dim Ret As Boolean
    Dim SalesStaging As String, SW As Range          

    SalesStaging = "SalesStaging.xlsm"
    Set salesWB = Workbooks.Open(SalesStaging)
    Set salesWB = Workbooks("SalesStaging.xlsm")
    Set mrpWB = ThisWorkbook


    With salesWB.Worksheets("SendToMRP")
        For Each SW In .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(3))
            With mrpWB.Worksheets("Sales & Returns").Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp)
                .Offset(1, 1) = SW.Offset(0, 0) ' OrderId
                .Offset(1, 2) = SW.Offset(0, 1) ' StoreFront
                .Offset(1, 3) = SW.Offset(0, 2) ' OrderType
                .Offset(1, 4) = SW.Offset(0, 3) ' PurchaseDate
                .Offset(1, 5) = SW.Offset(0, 4) ' ShipmentServiceLabelCategory
                .Offset(1, 6) = SW.Offset(0, 5) ' Title
                .Offset(1, 7) = SW.Offset(0, 6) ' SellersSKU
                .Offset(1, 8) = SW.Offset(0, 7) ' QtySold
                .Offset(1, 9) = SW.Offset(0, 8) ' ShippingCost
                .Offset(1, 10) = SW.Offset(0, 9) ' Discounts
                .Offset(1, 11) = SW.Offset(0, 10) ' ItemPrice
                ' .Offset(0, 0) = SW.Offset(0, 11) ' OrderTotal
                .Offset(1, 20) = SW.Offset(0, 12) ' LatestShipDate
                .Offset(1, 21) = SW.Offset(0, 13) ' SAState
                .Offset(1, 22) = SW.Offset(0, 14) ' SACity
                .Offset(1, 23) = SW.Offset(0, 15) ' SAPhone
                .Offset(1, 24) = SW.Offset(0, 16) ' SAPostalCode
                .Offset(1, 25) = SW.Offset(0, 17) ' SAName
                .Offset(1, 26) = SW.Offset(0, 18) ' SAddress
                .Offset(1, 27) = SW.Offset(0, 19) ' IsPrime
            End With
        Next
    End With
```

Comment: You're using the global `Rows` object - you need to use `mrpWB.Worksheets("Sales & Returns").Rows.Count`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are determining which row to write to by looking for the last non-empty cell in column A, but you never write anything to column A, therefore you will always be selecting the same row each time through the loop.

Try the following:

```
Dim salesWB As Workbook
Dim mrpWB As Workbook
Dim Ret As Boolean
Dim SalesStaging As String, SW As Range          

SalesStaging = "SalesStaging.xlsm"
Set salesWB = Workbooks.Open(SalesStaging)
Set salesWB = Workbooks("SalesStaging.xlsm")
Set mrpWB = ThisWorkbook


With salesWB.Worksheets("SendToMRP")
    For Each SW In .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(3))
        With mrpWB.Worksheets("Sales & Returns").Cells(mrpWB.Worksheets("Sales & Returns").Rows.count, 2).End(xlUp)
            .Offset(1, 0) = SW.Offset(0, 0) ' OrderId
            .Offset(1, 1) = SW.Offset(0, 1) ' StoreFront
            .Offset(1, 2) = SW.Offset(0, 2) ' OrderType
            .Offset(1, 3) = SW.Offset(0, 3) ' PurchaseDate
            .Offset(1, 4) = SW.Offset(0, 4) ' ShipmentServiceLabelCategory
            .Offset(1, 5) = SW.Offset(0, 5) ' Title
            .Offset(1, 6) = SW.Offset(0, 6) ' SellersSKU
            .Offset(1, 7) = SW.Offset(0, 7) ' QtySold
            .Offset(1, 8) = SW.Offset(0, 8) ' ShippingCost
            .Offset(1, 9) = SW.Offset(0, 9) ' Discounts
            .Offset(1, 10) = SW.Offset(0, 10) ' ItemPrice
            ' .Offset(0, 0) = SW.Offset(0, 11) ' OrderTotal
            .Offset(1, 19) = SW.Offset(0, 12) ' LatestShipDate
            .Offset(1, 20) = SW.Offset(0, 13) ' SAState
            .Offset(1, 21) = SW.Offset(0, 14) ' SACity
            .Offset(1, 22) = SW.Offset(0, 15) ' SAPhone
            .Offset(1, 23) = SW.Offset(0, 16) ' SAPostalCode
            .Offset(1, 24) = SW.Offset(0, 17) ' SAName
            .Offset(1, 25) = SW.Offset(0, 18) ' SAddress
            .Offset(1, 26) = SW.Offset(0, 19) ' IsPrime
        End With
    Next
End With
```

Comment: Thank you!! I really appreciate it!!